# How to display one html element over common boundary between other two html elements?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, antd

I want to display one HTML element (in my case it's the swap-button with a paired arrows) over the common border between the other two elements (in my case these are input boxes).
But my swap-button goes to the start of the page.

**HTML**

```
<div  style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexFlow: "row",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}>

             {/* origin input */}
             <div
              style={{
                marginTop: this.state.marginTop,
                border: "1px solid rgb(36, 2, 2)"
              }}
            >
              <h5 style={{ color: "white" }}>ORIGIN OF SHIPMENT</h5>
              <Dropdown name="origin" placeholder="ORIGIN OF SHIPMENT" />
            </div>



             {/* swap button */}
            <div>
              <h5>
                <span style={{ display: "inline-block", width: "0px" }}> 
              </span>
              </h5>
              <Button
                type="default"
                size="small"
                className={[this.state.css, "swap-button"]}
                shape="circle"
                onClick={this.onSwapLocation}
              >
                <Icon type="swap" />
              </Button>
              </div>


             {/* destination input */}
            <div style={{ marginTop: this.state.marginTop }}>
              <h5 style={{ color: "white" }}>DESTINATION OF SHIPMENT</h5>
              <Dropdown
                name="destination"
                placeholder="DESTINATION OF SHIPMENT"
              />
            </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.swap-button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: var(--whiteColor);
    color: var(--blueColor);
}
```

Expected swap-button image: [[image: Expected behaviour][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajYaA.png):

Actual swap-button  image: [image: Actual behaviour]:

I will appreciate your reply. thank you.

Edit01: I just want to show that swap-button over the other two input boxes. I have already written HTML and CSS. but when I use position: absolute the swap-button goes to start. I think I need some help in CSS (i.e. .swap-button class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Screenshot]

You have to add an extra container to the `swap` button and `Destination of Shipment` input so you can position the swap button precisely in the middle using position `absolute` just like you are doing.

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.swap-container {
  position: relative;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  background: #0084ff;
  top: 10px;
  left: -15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 8px;
  color: #fff;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" value="Origin of Shipment"/>
  <div class="swap-container">
    <button>Swap</button>
    <input type="text" value="Destination of Shipment"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. so nice of you. Here is the GIF. https://imgur.com/a/iEhViuu

Answer (score -2):

```
input#addr_from {
    border-right: 1px solid #cad3db;
}
```